# dotnet - Exclude specific files from code coverage analysis in Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, azure-devops, code-coverage

I want to exclude all the DTOs from the code coverage analysis made in Azure DevOps.

Below the pipeline that i use to run tests:

```
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: "Run Tests"
    inputs:
      command: "test"
      projects: |
        TestCodeCoverage\Domain.Tests\Domain.Tests.csproj
      arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --collect:"Code coverage" --settings TestCodeCoverage/cover.runsettings'
```

Below my runsettings file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RunSettings>
    <DataCollectionRunSettings>
        <DataCollectors>
            <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
                <Configuration>
                    <CodeCoverage>
                        <ModulePaths>
                            <Exclude>
                                <ModulePath>.*\.DTO\.*</ModulePath>
                            </Exclude>
                        </ModulePaths>
                        <!-- Microsoft recommends you do not change the following values: -->
                        <UseVerifiableInstrumentation>True</UseVerifiableInstrumentation>
                        <AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>True</AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>
                        <CollectFromChildProcesses>True</CollectFromChildProcesses>
                        <CollectAspDotNet>False</CollectAspDotNet>
                    </CodeCoverage>
                </Configuration>
            </DataCollector>
        </DataCollectors>
    </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

When i run locally the following command it produces a coverage.cobertura.xml file :

```
dotnet test --configuration Release --collect:"Code coverage"
```

When i run locally the following command no coverage.cobertura.xml file is created :

```
dotnet test --configuration Release --collect:"Code coverage" --settings ./cover.runsettings
```

To summarize :

How can i have a coverage.cobertura.xml file as output and exclude from code coverage all the files that contains "DTO" in the name ?

Comment: Did you check this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-code-coverage